# Effect of going over the credit limit on a credit card to your credit score?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score, credit-report, credit-limit

If I have a credit card balance that is over the credit limit, and I don't go under within 30-days, the provider will report the overage to the reporting agencies. If you have generally good credit (above 700) how much of an impact will the overage have on your limit? Does it depend on the amount of overage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A large chunk of your FICO is based on the % of utilization. Being at 99% is not much different from being at 101%, although I'm seeing references to an immediate/specific penalty for going over 100% (I've seen 5 point-deductions mentioned a few times, and also 29 point hits, but none of them from official sources of info).

The bottom line is that you were doing yourself harm as you got closer to 100% of the limit anyway. And yes, the further over you go, the worse your utilisation % is, the bigger the hit to your score.

In general these are quickly remedied issues. If you get it back under control you should be able to get back on track quickly.